# Reopen request / Edit request

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question [about server/network setup checklists](https://serverfault.com/q/424288/23513) seems to fit the FAQ for what I can tell, at least for the On Topic-ness of it. I got one great answer before it got closed, but I feel this could help the community. I understand it may not be "answerable" to choosing just one answer, but part of the Stackexchange philosophy is that we can edit and add information that may solve the problem at any time (of course, assuming it's not closed or deleted).

If my views are skewed, please feel free to tell me to get in line with everyone else, but I feel this question would help the community more if it were opened, even as just a Community Wiki. If in it's current form it is not a viable question, can I please get help to reword it or rewrite it so that it is constructive? I come from the SU world

Comment: A common problem we see is people reading only part of the FAQ, usually that part that, when taken on its own or out of context, appears to support their claim to validity.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Understandable. Maybe for a blog post that question would be a bit more appropriate?

Comment: Server Fault is a Q&A site. Whether your question is appropriate to a blog somewhere or not I cannot say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question fails the "Can this question have one true answer?" test.

You were soliciting opinion from a bunch of people about what they consider truth in an attempt to distil your own truth. There may be very good answers, and there is one, but there can never be one Truth answer if you catch my meaning.

Comment: Distilled truth only comes from bottles, preferably over ice.

Comment: Would converting to a CW help? Or is it just something to be left alone?

Comment: @Luke: probably not http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 3):

The close reason posted on the question pretty well sums it up

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion

While I mildly agree that a discussion/wiki on that topic could benefit the community, it's pretty explicitly not allowed. Should the site's scope be changed, or should there be a sysadmin job site? That's a different discussion unfortunately.